# Мульти WebHooks

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Имеется несколько сайтов. Как осуществить оповещение всех сайтов через webhooks, если на одну пару entityType-action можно повесить только один url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В remap 1.1 такой возможности нет. Этот функционал **планируется** сделать в remap 1.2.

Comment: а когда планируется его выход?

Answer (score -1):

Инициируйте вызов скрипта на вашем сервере, который ретранслирует ваш вебхук по необходимым адресам.